# US vs Non US DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

My program has to be able to compare not only  us style vs us style format but also us style `(mm/dd/yyyy)` vs non us style `(dd/mm/yyyy)`. How to do it? So far this is what I have and it only works to compare same style:

```
DateTime my_dt = new DateTime(); // this can be mm/dd or dd/mm
                                 // depending on where it run
DateTime new_dt = Convert.ToDateTime(us_dt);
int compare = DateTime.Compare(new_dt, my_dt);
```

when my_dt is dd/mm, I got error :

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at update.Program.Process(String ftp_path, String action)
```

Comment: Why does every new programmer always use `Convert.ToSomthing(` instead of the `Somthing.Parse(` methods?

Comment: Is your question "how to parse DateTime when I know culture for the string (and it is not equal current app culture)"?

Comment: Styles are used during the parsing, not comparing

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: A `DateTime` is a `DateTime` is a `DateTime` - it has **no formatting** and **no style** - it's just 8 bytes of data. Which means: once you have your variables of type `DateTime`, comparing them is **totally independent** of any string formatting - you're just comparing two `DateTime` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the `DateTime` objects isn't the the real problem, it's the parsing. Given you have 2 strict formats here i.e. `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` the following should work

```
DateTime my_dt = null;
// parse in either US/Non-US format (culture-independant)
DateTime.ParseExact(someDateStr, new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None out my_dt);
// parse in US format (culture-dependant)
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(result3, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
// compare the results
int compare = DateTime.Compare(my_dt, result3);
```

Comment: @JohnRyann this code would run on everything from .NET 2.0 upwards.

Comment: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at update.Program.Process(String ftp_path, String action)

Answer (score 1):

Format is a property of datetime string representation, i.e. `dt.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")`.

`System.DateTime` is format agnostic, independent and unaware. So you can compare any two isntances of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really illustrate what I think is your actual problem.  I am guessing you have two date strings in different cultural formats and you want to compare them.

First of all, you need to know the culture or the format of the strings or else you could have unpredictable results.

Cultures can be identified by an LCID.  You can find a list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/goglobal/bb964664.aspx).

So let's say you have a English (US) date string and a English (Canada) string, you could compare them like so:

```
string americanDateString = "12/31/2013";
string canadianDateString = "31/12/2013";

DateTime americanDate = DateTime.Parse(americanDateString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1033); // 1033 = English - United States culture code

DateTime canadianDate = DateTime.Parse(canadianDateString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(4105); // 4105= English - Canada culture code

int compare = DateTime.Compare(americanDate, canadianDate);
```

**EDIT:** You can also use locale short strings (eg. "en-US" or "en-CA") to lookup the CultureInfo as per abatishchev's answer.

Comment: "*First of all, you need to know the culture of the strings*" - not really, all you need is the formats. Once you have that, and it's consistent of course, you can parse in a culture *independant* manner.

Comment: @James That's true if you can assume all the dates to be in the same format.  Although if you run into a date that is of a different format such as "Dec 31, 2013" then ParseExact would fail.

Comment: Yep hence the comment "*and it's consistent of course*" :) It really boils down to how flexible you want to be with your data. For me, it's always best to be consistent so choose a format and stick with it (generally UTC works best).